# Rgdal add column to shapefile

Tags: rgdal

I open a shapefile with the rgdal lib:

```
foo <- readOGR(dsn="myfolder",layer="myshapefileWithoutEnding")
foo.df <- as(foo, "data.frame")
```

Then I add a column to the data frame with

```
foo.df$MY_VALUE <- myDataFrameWithOneColumn
```

The I check if it looks fine with print(foo.df) and it does, foo.df shows my values as a new column

Then I write the shapefile

```
writeOGR(foo, ".", myfilename, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

It saves 4 files, everything looks fine.

But when I open the shapefile in a viewer, I can't see my added column. Everything looks like before.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

OMG, I added a whole dataframe to my object. So in the end I have this:

```
 library(rgdal)  
 foo <- readOGR(dsn="myfolder",layer="myshapefileWithoutEnding")
 foo@data$MY_VALUE <- myDataFrameWithOneColumn[,1]
 writeOGR(foo, ".", myfilename, driver="ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

Now it works!